# Timing of UITextView paste method has changed

Tags: ios, uitextview, paste

For years my app has subclassed UITextView and overridden the paste method to do some cleanup on pasted text:

```
- (void)paste:(id)sender {
    [super paste:sender];

    NSString *pastedText = self.text;
    // do cleanup here
    self.text = pastedText;
}
```

But I just realized that now when this runs, self.text has not yet been updated with the pasted text. It still shows the original text, or an empty string if the field was empty, so the cleanup has no effect.

I don't know when this changed. A user just reported it and said the problem started a few weeks ago, so maybe the latest iOS update 11.4.1? But I've heard sporadic reports of this earlier and haven't been able to reproduce it. It does happen consistently now in 11.4.1.

I've added this workaround:

```
- (void)paste:(id)sender {
    [super paste:sender];
    [self performSelector:@selector(pasteCleanup) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
}

- (void)pasteCleanup {
    NSString *pastedText = self.text;
    // do cleanup here
    self.text = pastedText;
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Why not implement `shouldChangeTextInRange` delegate or listen for the `UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification` notification?

Comment: Those also run when typing text or changing the formatting. I only need to do this cleanup when pasting.